# Regex to replace integer between two pound / hash symbols in php

Tags: php, regex

Looking to replace `#678#` with:

```
<span id="note-678"></span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/#(\d+)#/', '<span id="note-$1"></span>', $str);
```